# What can I do if the past purchases page does not load in iTunes store app on iPad?

Tags: ipad, icloud, itunes-store

I have an iPad 3 and an iPhone 4 with the same iCloud account. On my iPhone I can load the past purchases page in iTunes Store app. The iPad does not load that page. It is light grey for a few seconds until it turns to a darker shade of grey. Nothing else happens.

Both devices run iOS 6.1.3. System language is German (if that matters).

I already restarted the iPad, logged out from and in to my account, activated Genius for apps (only to be able to deacivate it as suggested by some users with the same problem).

I have not yet completely restored my iPad. I only want to do that if nothing else would help.

Any ideas very much appreciated.

Comment: This is usually a sign that the servers that serve up your specific account's purchases can't get a good connection to the database storing your purchases. Have you determined if this is a persistent issue or perhaps something that's temporary and will clear itself up if you wait for a while? (From your details I'm mostly certain you've seen this for a while, but wonder if the two devices are polling a different server on the back end)

Comment: It seems to be persistent. At least, the problem exists for several weeks now.

Answer (score 1):

1. Disconnect and reconnect one last time from Settings / iTunes and App Store
2. Reset your network settings from Settings General / Reset
3. Make a backup and restore as new, connect with the AppleID and see if you can reproduce the issue "as new"